# Dojo Tooltips missing the mark sometimes

Tags: dojo, tooltip

I'm using tooltips for icons that are displayed in a dijit.Dialog. Sometimes they work just fine, but other times they get placed around 25 to 50 pixels further away from the target than they should be. I can't see any pattern to when this happens. Any ideas on why the screen placement would be varying in this way?

Thanks,

Karl

Comment: Do you use dijit.Tooltip? Could you add the code that you use to attach tooltips to the icons?

Comment: It's attached via inline javascript function connected to the onMouseOver event. I looked further into this and I think the 
dijit.placeOnScreenAroundNode library function is getting the position wrong, but I'm not yet sure why. Here's the code : 
 


this.buttonConnection2 = 

dojo.connect(this.toolButton, "onMouseOver", this, function(){

        new dijit.Tooltip({connectId: this.toolButton.id], 

             label:[this.toolJson.titleTxt]});

        });

Answer (score 0):

you can use dijit.showTooltip and dijit.hideTooltip. Here is an example on how to show tooltips on complex dijits such as FilteringSelect and ComboBox with this simple techinque

http://jsfiddle.net/jleviaguirre/Xqz8Z/6/